# Programmatically applying the Qt mouse-hover button highlighting on any button

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt application On Windows, when the mouse cursor hovers over a QPushButton, it will be highlighted with a shimmering outline.

I would like to tell any QPushButton to be highlighted like that, programmatically, without it having the mouse cursor actually hovering it.

Is this possible? I've tried setting focus to the button and played with different stylesheets, but I can't seem to access the mouse-hover outline effect.

Comment: Is QGraphicsDropShadowEffect what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't verify it now unfortunately - looked promising back then though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

If you want to simulate, that a button is constantly under the mouse, my solution would be to inherit from *QPushButton* and reimplement the `paintEvent` method, explicitly setting the state of the button to `QStyle::State_MouseOver`:

```
option.state |= QStyle::State_MouseOver;
```

**Note**: Please, be aware, that this solution will have different effects on different operating systems, as they use different ways to indicate a hovered button. Under Windows 7 for example the whole button will be highlighted, instead of adding a glowing border.

---

## Background

*QPushButton* is drawn by *QStylePainter*, as seen in the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qpushbutton.cpp.html#_ZN11QPushButton10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent):

```
void QPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
}
```

The way the button is drawn is determined by the settings held in [QStyleOptionButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionbutton.html), which is a subclass of [QStyleOption](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html). QStyleOption in turn has a public `state` attribute, which holds the [state flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StateFlag-enum) that are used when drawing the button. The flag `QStyle::State_MouseOver` is used to indicate that the button is under the mouse.

---

## Example

Finally, here is an example you could try:

In *GlowyButton.cpp*:

```
#include "GlowyButton.h"
#include <QStylePainter>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>

...

void GlowyButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/)
{
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    option.state |= QStyle::State_MouseOver;
    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
}

...
```

The full code of the example could be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-AlwaysHoveredButton).

Comment: This is an excellent example, but it could have been 15 lines in a single file instead of so much spread-out boilerplate: it's very hard to follow what's important, since >50% of it is irrelevant and unnecessary. As an aside, using `QMainWindow` is incorrect in most cases, as most simple applications don't need the docking window functionality it provides. It is very lamentable that Qt Creator comes with a template that defaults to `QMainWindow` as the base type. There are approximately 0 SO answers that ever need a `QMainWindow`, unless the question was about that class.

Comment: @KubaOber, I have considered what you have said in your comment and edit the answer accordingly. Thank you for the remarks!

Comment: Amazing answer @scopchanov - thanks! I will look into this now. I didn't know about the Woboq code browser - what a gem of a resource!